# How to write where clause in Google sheets to evaluate the values of different sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Let me say there are two sheets named `foo` and `master`.

When I set in B2 cell of `foo` the following query

`=query('master'!A1:A6, "select A where A='"&H1&"'")`

the B2 cell of `foo` extracts and gets the data on "`A` of `master`" where "the value of a cell of `A` column of `master`" **is coincident with "the value of `H1` of `master`"**.

However, my aim here is a bit different. I want to extract the same thing where "the value of a cell of `A` column of `master`" **is coincident with "the value of `H1`of `foo`"**

I guess I have to replace `'"&H1&"'` with something. Could  you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what your formula does already.

If you want `H1` to be fetched from `foo` assuming the query formula is located at `foo` your formula is correct:

```
=query('master'!A1:A6, "select A where A='"&H1&"'")
```

here `H1` is fetched from `foo` since you have put the formula in `foo`.

If you want to fetch the value of `H1` of master, then:

```
=query(master!A1:A6, "select A where A='"&master!H1&"'")
```

If you want to put this formula in a different sheet but grab the `H1` of `foo`, then again reference the sheet name:

```
=query(master!A1:A6, "select A where A='"&foo!H1&"'")
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know &H1& refers the `H1` of the current sheet.